# Filemaker type environment for MySQL development

Tags: mysql

I have experience of developing FileMaker and MySQL. Im used to developing MySQL longhand in php which is fine, but slow. Conversely, environments like FileMaker are very fast to write and deploy scripts and reports. Is there anything similar to FileMaker that allows me to quickly write queries and reports in MySQL and deploy?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think the best option might actually be FileMaker. Using the appropriate ODBC driver and FileMaker's [External SQL Sources](http://www.filemaker.com/support/technologies/sql.html) feature, you can use FileMaker to create a front-end to a MySQL database. After using this technology, MySQL tables will appear as FileMaker tables within FileMaker, and you can design layouts (data entry, queries and reports) just as if the tables existed within FileMaker.